# WebBrowser control displays html text directly instead of browser view of html

Tags: c#, .net, web-controls

I'm using WebBrowser control in .NET app. I construct a html text, then set the controls property DocumentText to this html. It works fine on my computer. On some other computers it simply displays the source as a text. I think that it may be connected with some explorer properties but I don't really know why it is behaving like this. How can I handle it to always display proper view? Or at least what can I fix on a specific computer so that the application works fine/

Comment: Is there a difference in the version of IE installed in these computers?

Comment: yes there is a different version. is it possible that it affects the application? how can  ihandle it so that it works everywhere?

Answer (score 0):

There is allways the sucky way of dumping the HTML to disk and set the URL to the file. But that is not a good solution.